# how to sort an characters in java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I'm trying to code a program to manipulate a string (String Array List) in a way that sorts it after shuffling.

It's meant to help solving a word-sort-game where up to 7 letters are shown in a ring, shuffled, and you have to find words of different lengths to win.

I am stuck right now with the sorting cause it sorts how it should be, but only the whole array list. I would need to sort it character by character, like:

-number of characters: 4

-chars: m,w,r,a

-output should look something like:

"Original List:"

m, w, r, a

"List after shuffling:"

```
m, a, w, r
w, m, r, a
a, r, m, w
w, a, r, m
```

...etc.

and after that step of shuffling where every possible combination is shown it should sort those outputs alphabetical like:

"List after sorting:"

```
a, m, r, w
a, m, w, r
a, r, m, w
a, r, w, m

m, a, r, w
m, a, w, r
m, r, a, w
m, r, w, a
m, w, a, r
m, w, r, a

r, a, m, w

...etc.
```

As I said, my problem is the last part. I searched here and other sites like geeksforgeeks etc. but couldn't find something useful for my approach. here is what I did so far. I also tried other stuff like `ArrayListTree` but that didn't work or I didn't get it to work for me cause of me being inexperienced.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SHUFFLE_SORT_TEST {

    public static  void main(String[] args)
    {           
        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        //Input number of elements in the String array

            System.out.println("How many 
                    characters?");

        int characterNumber = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        //get the characters (letters)
            for (int i = 1; i < 
                    characterNumber + 1; i++) {
                System.out.println("type in character number: " + i);
                String getChar = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();



                // add the letters to the String Array one after another

                myList.add(getChar);

                // Printing list before shuffling

                System.out.println("\n\n\nOriginal List : \n" + myList + "\n\n\n");


                /*shuffle (2^n)+1 times (n = number of characters) (2^n+1 is the maximimal number of different possibilities)*/


                //edit: 129 is enough cause max chars == 7 and 2^7+1 = 129

                int n = 129;

                for (int j = 1; j < (n) + 1; j++) {


                    Collections.shuffle(myList);


                    // Printing list after shuffling

                    System.out.println(" \n" + myList + "         " +  j +"\n");

                }          

                //Sort the list

                Collections.sort(myList);      

                System.out.println(" \n" + myList + "         " + "SORTED" +"\n");

            }
    } 
}
```

I just cant figure out a way to sort my array list char by char and to get rid of duplicate entries to my unsorted list.

Comment: I formatted your code and edited out the part where you justify it being badly formatted because you're coding on your phone. And I also removed abbreviations, liberal use of ellipses, details which are not important to the question. For the future, *you* are the one asking for help, so making your question presentable and easy to read is on you.

Comment: Why are you shuffling?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve isn't just "sorting" or "shuffling", it's ***permutation***, i.e. generating every possible ordering of a sequence. Permutation has factorial complexity, i.e. the number of possibilities for *n* items is `n!`, not `2^n - 1`. For example, for 5 items, there are 120 possibilities `5! = 5*4*3*2*1 = 120`.

There is a fairly basic way of writing a recursive program that performs permutation. Basically, take the first element of the list; swap it with each element of the rest of the list; and with each swap, generate the permutation of the rest of the list. For a clearer explanation, you can just look up how to permute a list using recursion.

This is how you would implement it in Java:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

public class Permutation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type in up to 7 letters (no spaces): ");
        String input = scan.nextLine().trim();
        if (input.length() > 7) {
            input = input.substring(0, 7);
        }
        Set<String> possibilities = permutation(input);
        for (String s : possibilities) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static Set<String> permutation(String input) {
        // LinkedHashSet preserves the order in which we generate values
        // If you want the values sorted instead, use TreeSet
        Set<String> output = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        perm(input.toCharArray(), 0, output);
        return output;
    }

    public static void perm(char[] input, int start, Set<String> output) {
        if (start + 1 >= input.length) {
            // we've reached the end of the input, so record the current state
            output.add(String.valueOf(input));
            return;
        }
        // for first recursion, don't swap anything
        perm(input, start + 1, output);
        for (int i = start + 1; i < input.length; i++) {
            char a = input[start];
            char b = input[i];
            // for each successive recursion, swap the next character
            input[start] = b;
            input[i] = a;
            // run permutation for the rest of the list
            perm(input, start + 1, output);
            // and swap back when it's done
            input[start] = a;
            input[i] = b;
        }
    }
}
```